# Custom Modal with next and previous jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am in a struggle in implementing this next and previous button using jQuery. I'm implementing my own personalize modal or popup. And is goes like this.

CSS:

```
.grid-a1{ width: 500px; height: auto; background: #ededed; overflow: hidden; padding: 10px; margin: 5px; }
.link-a1{ color: #000; border: 1px solid #000; border-radius: 2px; padding: 5px; width: 300px; cursor: pointer; }
.panel-a1{ width: 100%; height: auto; overflow: hidden; padding: 5px; margin: 5px 0px; border-top: 1px solid #000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000; opacity: 1; -webkit-transition: all .2s; -o-transition: all .2s; transition: all .2s; }
.panel-a2{ position: fixed; top: -150%; right: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; margin: auto; background: #fff; color: #000; width: 500px; height: 100px; padding: 10px; text-align: center; overflow: hidden; z-index: 999; -webkit-transition: all .5s; -o-transition: all .5s; transition: all .5s; }
.overlay-panel{ position: fixed; z-index: 998; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; display: none; }
.next, .previous{ border: 2px solid #000; border-radius: 3px; padding: 3px; margin: 3px; color: #000; display: block; cursor: pointer; }
.opac{ opacity: 0 !important; }
.in{ top: 0 !important; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="grid-a1">
    <div class="link-a1">
        Clickable
    </div>        
    <div class="panel-a1">
        Content
    </div>
    <div class="overlay-panel"></div>
    <div class="panel-a2">
        Content

        <span class="next">Next</span> <span class="previous">Previous</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="grid-a1">
    <div class="link-a1">
        Clickable
    </div>        
    <div class="panel-a1">
        Content 2
    </div>
    <div class="overlay-panel"></div>
    <div class="panel-a2">
        Content 2

        <span class="next">Next</span> <span class="previous">Previous</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="grid-a1">
    <div class="link-a1">
        Clickable
    </div>        
    <div class="panel-a1">
        Content 2
    </div>
    <div class="overlay-panel"></div>
    <div class="panel-a2">
        Content 2

        <span class="next">Next</span> <span class="previous">Previous</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('body').on('click', '.link-a1', function() {
    $(this).closest('.grid-a1').find('.panel-a1').addClass('opac');
    $(this).closest('.grid-a1').find('.panel-a2').addClass('in');
    $(this).closest('.grid-a1').find('.overlay-panel').fadeIn();
});

$('body').on('click', '.overlay-panel', function() {
    $(this).closest('.grid-a1').find('.panel-a1').removeClass('opac');
    $(this).closest('.grid-a1').find('.panel-a2').removeClass('in');
    $(this).closest('.grid-a1').find(this).fadeOut();
});
```

How do I implement it in jQuery when I click on the next button it goes to the next `div` and closes the current one same as clicking the previous button. Any answers are much appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: could you make jsFiddle for this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mxdstvhx/ here @Amy :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, and http://jsfiddle.net/mxdstvhx/10/

```
$('body').on('click', '.next', function(){
   $(this).parents('.grid-a1').find('.overlay-panel').click();
   $(this).parents('.grid-a1').next('.grid-a1').find('.link-a1').click();
});

$('body').on('click', '.previous', function(){
   $(this).parents('.grid-a1').find('.overlay-panel').click();
   $(this).parents('.grid-a1').prev('.grid-a1').find('.link-a1').click();
});

$('body').on('click', '.link-a1', function() {
  $(this).closest('.grid-a1').find('.panel-a1').addClass('opac');
  $(this).closest('.grid-a1').find('.panel-a2').addClass('in');
  $(this).closest('.grid-a1').find('.overlay-panel').fadeIn();
  if ($(this).parents('.grid-a1').prev('.grid-a1').size() == 0) {
    $(this).parents('.grid-a1').find('.previous').hide();
  }
  if ($(this).parents('.grid-a1').next('.grid-a1').size() == 0) {
    $(this).parents('.grid-a1').find('.next').hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: Sir ? Can I ask something. If the div that is being selected is the first one I want the prev button to be hide same as the div being selected is the last one the next button will be hide. How will I implement such Sir ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here are the 2 events which will work for your `next` and `previous` button

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/mxdstvhx/11/)**

```
$('.next').on('click',function(){

    $('.grid-a1').find('.panel-a1').removeClass('opac');
    $('.grid-a1').find('.panel-a2').removeClass('in');
    $('.overlay-panel').fadeOut();
    if($(this).parents().closest('.grid-a1').nextAll().length!=0)
    {
        $(this).parents().closest('.grid-a1').next('.grid-a1').find('.panel-a1').addClass('opac');
        $(this).parents().closest('.grid-a1').next('.grid-a1').find('.panel-a2').addClass('in');
        $(this).parents().closest('.grid-a1').next('.grid-a1').find('.overlay-panel').fadeIn();
    }
});

$('.previous').on('click',function(){
    $('.grid-a1').find('.panel-a1').removeClass('opac');
    $('.grid-a1').find('.panel-a2').removeClass('in');
    $('.overlay-panel').fadeOut();
    if($(this).parents().closest('.grid-a1').prevAll().length!=0)
    {
        $(this).parents().closest('.grid-a1').prev('.grid-a1').find('.panel-a1').addClass('opac');
        $(this).parents().closest('.grid-a1').prev('.grid-a1').find('.panel-a2').addClass('in');
        $(this).parents().closest('.grid-a1').prev('.grid-a1').find('.overlay-panel').fadeIn();
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

To avoid `next` and `previous` is `last` and `first` steps respectively check the below demo and code

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/mxdstvhx/17/)**

```
$('.next:last').addClass('last').hide();
$('.previous:first').addClass('first').hide();

$('.next').on('click',function(){

    $('.grid-a1').find('.panel-a1').removeClass('opac');
    $('.grid-a1').find('.panel-a2').removeClass('in');
    $('.overlay-panel').fadeOut();
    if($(this).parents().closest('.grid-a1').nextAll().length!=0)
    {
        var showingElem=$(this).parents().closest('.grid-a1').next('.grid-a1');
        showingElem.find('.panel-a1').addClass('opac');

        showingElem.find('.panel-a2').addClass('in');
        showingElem.find('.overlay-panel').fadeIn();
        if(showingElem.find('.next').hasClass('last'))
            $(showingElem.find('.next').hide());
        else
            $(showingElem.find('.next').show());
    }

});

$('.previous').on('click',function(){

    $('.grid-a1').find('.panel-a1').removeClass('opac');
    $('.grid-a1').find('.panel-a2').removeClass('in');
    $('.overlay-panel').fadeOut();
    if($(this).parents().closest('.grid-a1').prevAll().length!=0)
    {
        var showingElem=$(this).parents().closest('.grid-a1').prev('.grid-a1');
        showingElem.find('.panel-a1').addClass('opac');
        showingElem.find('.panel-a2').addClass('in');
        showingElem.find('.overlay-panel').fadeIn();
        if(showingElem.find('.previous').hasClass('first'))
            $(showingElem.find('.previous').hide());
        else
            $(showingElem.find('.previous').show());
    }
});
```

Comment: Sweet. Thanks a lot Sir. I've spent whole day just to figure out this. You've save my time Sir. Thanks. Have a great day :)

Comment: Sir ? Can I ask something. If the div that is being selected is the first one I want the prev button to be hide same as the div being selected is the last one the next button will be hide. How will I implement such Sir ? Thanks

Comment: @John.. Updated the answer! check and let me know!! Anyways!! Happy coding.. :)

Comment: Done checking it Sir. It works like a charm :) Thank you for updating it :)

Comment: Anytime!! :) Have a nice day!! :)